# print complex number from fortran in c

Tags: c, fortran

So I have an array that was initiated as

`COMPLEX(KIND=GP), ALLOCATABLE, DIMENSION (:,:,:) :: C1,C2`

(not my code) in fortran, and I'm simply trying to print an element of this array using c code.

This is the c code I have,

```
    #include <stdio.h>

typedef struct com{
long double r, i;
} x;

void printfunc_(x* k){

        printf("Reading from fortran: %Le\t %Le\n", k->r, k->i);
}
```

and in fortran I call:

```
CALL printFUNC(C1(k,j,i))
```

k, j, i are ints.

But I only get 0.000000e+00

I don't know what GP is, but from looking up fortran code it looks like it can be 4, 8, or 16.

I've tried the c code with the struct being float, double, and long double. With the two former I get -0.000000 and 0.000000. I know there should be values by looking at the actual output: small single precision floats.

Comment: Do you have access to a modern Fortran compiler (2003+)? You may want to look at the intrinsic module `iso_c_binding` or the header `ISO_Fortran_binding.h`.

Comment: @jlokimlin It's a pretty large simulation using f90. I wouldn't even know where to begin in changing it -- the Makefile, that is.

Comment: what C compiler and platform?  (some windows setups have trouble with `long double` and `printf`)

Comment: @crablegs you do not really need to change anything else, just use the iso-c-binding for the interaction with C-Code. Basically, all compilers support that by now.

Comment: `CALL printFUNC(C3(k,j,i))` refers to an array which is not in your declarations.  You'll probably tell us it's a typo or an omission -- which is one of the reasons it's important to show your code, not just something a bit like some of your code.

Comment: You can just print what GP is, it is just a number, print it. You can also print `bitsize(C3(k,j,i))` or `sizeof()` if your compiler supports it.

Comment: When you tried float or double, did you also try %20.10f etc (rather than %Le)?

Comment: @VladimirF good call (duh). GP = 4.

Comment: @roygvib I'll give that a go.

Comment: @haraldkl sounds good. I will give that a go as well.